# Extend case class with typeclass

Tags: scala, functional-programming, polymorphism, typeclass, case-class

I have this code

```
  case class Salary(employee: String, amount: Double){

  }

  trait XN[M] {
    def x2(m: M): M
    def x3(m: M): M
    def x4(m: M): M
  }
```

I want to extend Salary with XN trait in order for the following test to work:

```
test("Salary is extended with xN") {

    val bobSalary = Salary("Bob", 100.0)

    bobSalary.x2 shouldBe Salary("Bob", 200.0)
    bobSalary.x3 shouldBe Salary("Bob", 300.0)
    bobSalary.x4 shouldBe Salary("Bob", 400.0)

  }
```

My attempts:

#1

```
  implicit val SalaryXN: XN[Salary] = new XN[Salary] {
    override def x2(m: Salary): Salary = m.copy(amount = m.amount * 2)

    override def x3(m: Salary): Salary = m.copy(amount = m.amount * 3)

    override def x4(m: Salary): Salary = m.copy(amount = m.amount * 4)
  }
```

#2

```
  object Salary extends XN[Salary] {
    override def x2(m: Salary): Salary = new Salary(employee = m.employee, amount = m.amount * 2)

    override def x3(m: Salary): Salary = new Salary(employee = m.employee, amount = m.amount * 3)

    override def x4(m: Salary): Salary = new Salary(employee = m.employee, amount = m.amount * 4)
  }
```

How to do that?

[Online code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XtoVqIPgQneMYm3Oii29yg)

Comment: The definition of `x2` says it takes an argument of type `M`. Therefore `bobSalary.x2` _should be_ type `Salary => Salary`, a function that takes a `Salary` and returns a `Salary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that `XN` is a **typeclass**, it would be better to properly use that pattern instead of relying on a *(discouraged)* **implicit conversion**.

```
trait XN[M] {
  def x2(m: M): M
  def x3(m: M): M
  def x4(m: M): M
}

object XN {
  object syntax {
    implicit class XNOp[M](private val m: M) extends AnyVal {
      @inline final def x2(implicit ev: XN[M]): M = ev.x2(m)
      @inline final def x3(implicit ev: XN[M]): M = ev.x3(m)
      @inline final def x4(implicit ev: XN[M]): M = ev.x4(m)
    }
  }
}

final case class Salary(employee: String, amount: Double)
object Salary {
  implicit final val SalaryXN: XN[Salary] =
    new XN[Salary] {
      override def x2(s: Salary): Salary = s.copy(amount = s.amount * 2)
      override def x3(s: Salary): Salary = s.copy(amount = s.amount * 3)
      override def x4(s: Salary): Salary = s.copy(amount = s.amount * 4)
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
import XN.syntax._

val bobSalary = Salary("Bob", 100.0)

bobSalary.x2
// res: Salary = Salary("Bob", 200.0)
```

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/jFu1khzWSmGl3jxTIDOkIg)*.

Comment: I'm curious to see the documentation supporting your "(discouraged) implicit conversion". This would be good information to know!

Comment: @RandombessSlayer while by now this is mostly understood as a general community guideline, you can find a lot of arguments / discussions about why **implicit conversions** are discouraged _(not meaning you shouldn't use them never, but try to minimise them and consider alternatives)_. However, [here](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/can-we-wean-scala-off-implicit-conversions/4388) you can find the creator of the language himself arguing they are _"bad"_ and discussing with others if they can be removed in **Scala 3**. But, IMHO, the main problem with them is that they are obscure.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez oh man, you saved me so many times

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that's a great read, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[Use Accepted solution, implicits are tricky!]

greg made a great start, but as written it won't work in your solution.

Here are a few changes:

Still using:

```
case class Salary(employee: String, amount: Double) // As before
```

You can either call the method on a `Salary` or pass it a `Salary`, you're trying to do both.

The simplest would be to try:

```
trait XN[M] {
    def x2: M
    def x3: M
    def x4: M
  }

implicit def salary2XN(s: Salary): XN[Salary] = {
    new XN[Salary] {
      override def x2: Salary = s.copy(amount = 2 * s.amount)
      override def x3: Salary = s.copy(amount = 3 * s.amount)
      override def x4: Salary = s.copy(amount = 4 * s.amount)
    }
  }
```

And now you can call each method using your signature:

```
Salary("bob", 200).x2
```

EDIT:

A solution using plain old extension:

```
trait XN[M] {
    def x2: M
    def x3: M
    def x4: M
  }

  case class Salary(employee: String, amount: Double) extends XN[Salary] {
    override def x2: Salary = Salary(employee, 2 * amount)
    override def x3: Salary = Salary(employee, 3 * amount)
    override def x4: Salary = Salary(employee, 4 * amount)
  }
```

Which you can now call the exact same way:

```
Salary("bob", 233).x2
```

NOTE: In the former implementation, `Salary`s themselves do not have the methods of the `XN`, rather we apply them to each Salary using an implicit conversion. With the latter implementation, EVERY `Salary` has the methods for `XN`, we define it in the implementation of the `case class` itself.

Comment: It would be better to just use the typeclass pattern correctly + extension methods.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez agreed. If you feel strongly about it, I invite you to post an answer to address that. Your comment, while insightful to people who understand the language, means very little to people who aren't familiar with the pattern. For example, someone who wishes to know the answer to a similar question may come across this, look at the accepted answer, see the comment, and know not what you mean. You bring up a good point, explain it!

Comment: I added an answer after making the comment. And it seems you are confusing **extension methods** with **inheritance**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez can you direct me to resources on "extension methods"? To be quite honest, I'm not familiar with that pattern, or at least I don't recognize the name.

Comment: An [**extension method**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_methods) is adding additional methods to an existing class, so you can call it on instances _(objects)_ of that class like if they were normal methods, that is the reason of the name. In **Scala 2** we model that using [**implicit classes**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html), which look similar to **implicit conversions** _(and actually use them under the hood)_, but they are considered two different things, and **extension methods** are not discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Creating implicit conversion from Salary to XN could be a solution. This is how scala add new functionality to existing classes without extending them.

```
implicit def salary2XN(s: Salary): XN[Salary] = {
  new XN[Salary] {
    override def x2: Salary = Salary(s.employee, 2*s.amount)
    override def x3: Salary = Salary(s.employee, 3*s.amount)
    override def x4: Salary = Salary(s.employee, 4*s.amount)
  }
}
```